# Custom Mapping Spring Data ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I wan to make use of elastic search shape queries which work well with spring-data-es so far. The problem is when creating the index from my java application the automatic mapping looks like this:

```
 "shape" : {
    "properties" : {
       "coordinates" : {
          "type" : "double"
       },
       "type" : {
          "type" : "string"
       }
    }
}
```

So it just Indexes all my coordinates as double array while I need this:

```
"shape": {
  "type": "geo_shape",
  "tree": "quadtree",
  "precision": "5m"
}
```

So. How to implement a custom mapping? There is a annotation called @GeoPointField which makes a GeoPoint mapping. That one looks not to complicated so implementing this by myself shouldn't be to much of a problem but I can't find the implementation for the annotation and so I'm kinda stuck. Also ok would be to use: `ElasticSearchTemplate.putMapping(indexName, type, mapping)` but I can't find what to put into mapping as its Type Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into the exact same issue a while ago and the problem is that Spring Data ES (as of May 11th, 2016) doesn't support geo shapes. As can be seen in [DATAES-169](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-169), the issue hasn't gotten much traction yet.

For this reason, I've [forked the official spring-data-elasticsearch](https://github.com/consulthys/spring-data-elasticsearch) repository and decided to implement it myself.

I've made it work for polygons and circles, but I haven't pushed my code yet. I intend to support all shapes before pushing and submitting a PR. Stay tuned...

Comment: Indexing and retrieving is no Problem. I just cannot get the mapping to work. If I create the index myself with the correct Mapping the spatial queries all work. My only property in the class is this: ```private GeoJsonObject shape;``` The dependcy for that is ```de.grundid.opendatalab:geojson-jackson:1.5.1```. maybe this makes your life easier.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point. If you use Spring Data entities and expect them to create proper `geo_shape` field mappings, it won't work as is. Changes are required to be made in `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder` (among others). If you use `ElasticSearchTemplate.putMapping()` in order to bootstrap your `geo_shape` mapping, you run the risk of having Spring Data trying to create a conflicting field mapping (since it doesn't know anything about `geo_shape`)

Comment: The putMapping would be a dirty work around. Currently I create the index via a shell script and then everything works fine. I can put Polygons, Multipolygons and Points into the index without problems via repository.save() and with GeoShapeQueryBuilder I can use them to get data.

The only thing I am missing is an annotation which tells spring at creation time to use that mapping.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's the missing piece. As it stands, Spring Data ES will not create such a mapping for you... until I push my changes, that is, or you do it on your side :)

Comment: Why is it different for polygons and circles and anything else? Isn't it just a FieldType that needs to be implemented?

Comment: You can definitely add a `@GeoShapeField` annotation in `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations`, but you also need to modify `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder` in order to take it into account and create the proper `geo_shape` mapping for those fields. Also worth noting that Circle is not supported by the GeoJSON spec, but I'm supporting it anyway, in order to be compatible with ES.

Comment: Got it. Can I swap out the Mapping class without anything else? Using spring-boot and stuff to manage everything.

Comment: You're probably better off forking the repo, making the required modifications to MappingBuilder + the new annotation and then rebuild your own JAR. Should not take more than an hour. I'm about to push my stuff, if you're ok to wait.

Comment: I've just pushed my changes on the [1.3.x branch](https://github.com/consulthys/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/1.3.x). You can check it out, run `mvn install` and you'll get a pretty 1.3.5-BUILD-SNAPSHOT JAR you can use to shake it out. Just annotate your `GeoJsonObject ` with `@GeoShapeField` and magic will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance I just struggle to include a self forked jar for this. I took the class from the latest 1.4.x and already changed what I need to (working with ES 2.x). Spring is normally highly configurable and I just search where I can tell it to take my patched class instead of the other.

Comment: OK, as long as it works for you. Once the requirements are satisfied, I'll submit an official PR to the Spring folks...

Comment: Would be great with maybe even a new ticket as the one you posted is outdated. The link provided in it isn't even working anymore.

Comment: @Val did you got any news for this support?